# Selection based on a button is click. without using buttonclick event

Tags: .net, wpf, radio-button

I am developing a WPF application where i have 2 radiobuttons having "same Groupname".

1. Blue
2. Black

also i have CLEAR button. once application is opened, "blue" radiobutton is selected by default.

if i click "Black" radiobutton and if i click CLEAR button, i want the control back to Blue.

I do not want to use Buttonclick event in .cs file or something like this.
I want to use IsChecked property to be binded to the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EventTrigger` on on the `Button.Click` event to run a `BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames` to set the `RadioButton` `IsChecked` property

Example

```
 <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton x:Name="blue" Content="Blue" IsChecked="True"/>
        <RadioButton Content="Black" />
        <Button Content="Clear">
            <Button.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="blue" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
```

So this will check the `Blue` `RadioButton` when the `Button` is clicked